# How to test if a react component was clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component called HelpButton, which looks like this:

```
import helpLogo from '../Resources/helplogo.svg';

function HelpButton(props) {

    const [isOpen, setisOpen] = React.useState(false)

    function toggle() {
        setisOpen(prevIsOpen => !isOpen)
        if (isOpen)
            console.log("Help Open")
        else
            console.log("Help Closed")
    }

    return (
        <div className="helpIconBgrnd" onClick={toggle} data-testid="helpIconBgrnd">
            <img className="help-icon" src={helpLogo} alt='help-icon' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default HelpButton
```

I want to test if this component was clicked and I know there is an approach where you use `expect(mockCallbackFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(number)`. But the problem is that I do not pass the toggle function as a prop to HelpButton, instead it is declared inside the HelpButton component, so I don't think I can use this approach.
How can I test if the HelpButton component was clicked?

Comment: You should render some elements based on the `isOpen` and test if the element is rendered.

Comment: How did you use `isOpen` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to check in 'Some Component' whether HelpButton Component is open or not?

Try this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Parent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);

  //now you know if the component is open, you can do whatever you need with it

  const handleToggle = () => setisOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <HelpButton onToggle={handleToggle}/>
  )
}  

export default Parent;

const HelpButton ({ onToggle }) {
  return (
    <div className="helpIconBgrnd" onClick={onToggle} data-testid="helpIconBgrnd">
      <img className="help-icon" src={helpLogo} alt='help-icon' />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HelpButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try This. It's re-render while isOpen property is changed.

```
useEffect(()=>{
toggle();
},[isOpen]);
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little? I am really new to React and not completely sure how to use useEffect